# Conectar Entity Framework con SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

llevo un buen rato en esto pero el problema es el mismo

```
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=jobs;User ID=sa;Password=Pass@word;Trust Server Certificate=False");
            }
        }
```

y este es el resultado

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
```

Los datos son correctos, pero no quiere conectarse

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El mensaje de error dice: "The server was not found or was not accessible". Asegúrate que la instancia es la correcta y que puedes acceder a ella. Ya intentaste con MSSQL Management Studio?

Comment: Hola @Arriel , todos los clientes posibles se pueden conectar, incluso via sentencia SQL, incluso generé todo esto conectandome a la base de datos, una ingeniera inversa, pero EF no puede acceder

Comment: no utilices `localhost`, si usas localhost que sea adjuntando su nombre de instancia: `localhost\{instancia}`. en su lugar utiliza `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: `127.0.0.1` Y `localhost` son lo mismo.